# Tubular glue remover for CARBON

Tags: tire, rims, tubular

Trying to find a tubular glue remover that won't eat carbon. Acetone is a no (unless very dilute??) and apparently so is the top brand that claims to be carbon safe (see picture). Any ideas?[image]

Comment: I guess you already have glued tubulars on the rim?  It may be helpful to use tubular tape next time, though it doesn't help in the now.

Comment: Why are you capitalising CARBON?

Answer (score 3):

You can try a light lubricating spray like GT-85.

I've had success with this and some wire wool when working on a metal rim. For a carbon rim you'll want to find an alternative to wire wool, of course, but the lubricant in my experience works to soften the glue enough that it can be scraped or abraded off.